# JavaFX: Application thread doesnt terminate after closing window

Tags: java, javafx, terminate

I am trying to terminate the thread that runs the JavaFX application when I close the window, without closing any other threads. This is my application class:

```
package testIt;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MemoryVisualizerApp extends Application{


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

//Setup the scene and launch with given properties
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/MemoryVisualizer.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 650, 340);
    //Set whether the screen should be re-sizable (possibly best size = default)
    primaryStage.setResizable(true);
    primaryStage.setMinHeight(300);
    primaryStage.setMinWidth(550);
    primaryStage.setTitle("MINT Performance");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("testIt/MemoryVisualizer.css");
    primaryStage.show();
    primaryStage.show();
    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() 
            {
                public void handle(WindowEvent e){
                    System.out.println("test");  
                    try {
                        stop();
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
}

}
```

For testing purposes, this app is the only thing running when I start the program, and so when I close the window, the entire program should terminate. But I still have the option to terminate the program (I'm using eclipse and the red square is still clickable), meaning the thread is still active.

How can I have it so that this thread terminates after closing the GUI window?

Comment: it should exit without using the `setOnCloseRequest()`. Can you try and let us know what happens after removing this method and commenting out one of the two `stage.show()` that you have used ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`Platform.exit()`** instead of **`stop()`**

```
 primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() 
  {
      public void handle(WindowEvent e){
          System.out.println("test");  
          try {
               Platform.exit();
          } 
          catch (Exception e1) {
               e1.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
   });
```

[Take a look at the JavaFX Application life cycle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html)

Comment: Thats what I thought, but I did that and it still isnt terminating. The read square still allows me to terminate the app.

Comment: Good catch, I've deleted the second one, however it didnt fix the problem

Comment: Check your MemoryVisualizer.fxml's controller code. May be you create Threads there and forget to stop that.

Comment: I do have a schedule executor thread that is created, but I'm not sure how to stop it once I close the window

Comment: Make that thread(scheduled executor thread) accessible through the controller. You can stop it from the MemoryVisualizerApp class.

Comment: The issue is not with JavaFX at all, it is with your MemoryVisualizer code, you need to [shutdown the ScheduledExecutorService that you started](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--), (note that for this to work, your threading code needs to be well behaved to handle the shutdown interruption) - pretty hard to advise further without having your actual threading code in the question.

Comment: @jewelsea Trying to edit the code to put the threading portion in there, but its giving me a hard time. Should be up soon

Comment: Here is an example for how you can get variables from controller class
https://gist.github.com/cooljith91112/5a2f6250b987266adaa1

Comment: Or, just define a `shutdown()` method in the controller class that calls `shutdown()` on the executor service. Then invoke the controller's shutdown in your application's `stop()` method. That avoids exposing the implementation details of your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the stop() method:

```
@Override
public void stop(){
    System.exit(0);
}
```

This will cause the application to stop running in the IDE.